# Cannot send messages to discord channel anymore

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I recently noticed that my discordbot stopped working, I haven't upgraded anything on my server and it just stopped working.

I noticed in the logs. Figured I had old versions of packages and I upgraded to discord.js v13 and everything borked even more.

```
discclient.channels.fetch(item.channel[i]).send(msgembed)
```

Now i'm stuck here.

```
index2.js:46
                                channel.send({ embeds: [msgembed] });
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

Anyone got an idea? Have they changed alot of stuff?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GuildChannelManager#fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a promise, you have to resolve it before trying to access the channel.

```js
discclient.channels.fetch(item.channel[i])
   .then(channel => channel.send({ embeds: [msgembed] }))
   .catch(console.error);
```

[Guide for Updating from v12 to v13](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html)

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that the channel doesn't exist.
Try fetching and verifying if it found it, before sending the message.

Comment: This would be more suited as a comment.